# How to write a for loop to assign an array of "Food" to an object called "Wolf"?

Tags: java, foreach

For my assignment, I have been asked to complete the following:

**1.** Create a second method called eat in the Animal class. This method should take a Food object and an Integer as parameters.

**2.** Use an appropriate loop in the new eat method to feed the Food object to the Animal, the number of times specified in the Integer parameter.

So far my attempt looks like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Wolf extends Carnivore
{

    ArrayList<Food> foodGroup = new ArrayList<>();

    abstract public Food eat(Food x, int b) throws Exception;
    {
        Wolf y = new Wolf();
        ArrayList<Food> foodGroup1 = y.foodGroup;
        addFood(new Food("Chicekn"));
        addFood(new Food("Pork"));
        addFood(new Food("Steak"));
        Wolf wolf1 = new Wolf();

        for (Food x : wolf1.eat(foodGroup1) {

            //How to find out the amount of times x has iterated?
            System.out.println(//print out the amount of times food has bee fed to the wolf);   
    }

    }
public void addFood(Food inFood)
{
  foodGroup.add(inFood);
}
}
```

I know attempt probably has many mistakes, but I'm still new to Java and am learning what others would see as simple concepts. Any help on how to fix this for loop to print out the desired outcome would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

P.s. Wolf class is an extension of the Animal class.

Comment: Why do you have the keyword `abstract` in your method declaration when you aren't using an abstract class?

Comment: The method is inherited from an abstract method within an abstract class so it has to be abstract itself.

Comment: No, no, no. That's not how abstract methods work. Once you provide an implementation, the method is no longer abstract. Get rid of the `abstract` modifier and get rid of the semicolon after `Exception` at the end of the line. What you have now won't compile because the class is not declared `abstract`. You've also created an instance initialization block rather than a method body in the code following the method declaration.

Comment: Is `Carnivore` abstract? If so, you don't need the `abstract` keyword when declaring that method in the concrete class. I would suggest adding the `@Override` annotation, though.

Comment: Can you provide a little more information about your `foodGroup` `ArrayList`? What exactly is it's purpose?

Comment: Carnivore is abstract, and I got the method deceleration part completely wrong.

Comment: If the `eat` method is supposed to get an animal to eat the `Food` given by the parameter, why is this method (or the code that you thought was part of your method) creating new `Food` and giving it to the animal, instead of the `Food` you're supposed to feed it?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
public void eat(Food food, int count) {
    while (count > 0) {
        addFood(food);
        count--;
    }
}
```

Note that since you are creating an implementation of `eat`, you should *not* declare it `abstract`. Also, there's no reason to declare that it throws anything, because there's nothing in the implementation that throws an exception. (Later you might want to throw an exception if the `count` is negative. But if you do, then you should declare the method to throw some specific type of exception—probably `IllegalArgumentException`—not the very broad `Exception`.)

As an aside, the `abstract` declaration and the semicolon mean that your class actually has a completely different structure than you think. It actually has the following members:

1. a field `foodGroup`;
2. an abstract method `eat(Food,int)`l
3. An instance initializer block (the code between the braces that follow the declaration of `eat`);
4. A method `addFood(Food)`.

An *initializer block* is a piece of code at the top level of a class. If it is preceded by the `static` keyword, it is a *static initializer block* and is executed once when the class is first loaded. If it does not have the `static` keyword, then it is an *instance initializer block* and the compiler adds a copy of the block to each class constructor (including the default constructor, if you don't declare any constructors of your own).

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your `eat` method:

1. You're not returning anything so return type needs to be `void`
2. As pointed out in a comment you don't need the `abstract` keyword in the implementation
3. Why in the world are you newing up 2 `Wolf`s? It makes no sense to be calling `eat` on a new instance of `Wolf`, you're not even passing it the right types. You're passing in `ArrayList<Food>` not `Food` an `int`, it just makes no sense
4. You're not using your input params anywhere
5. `for (Food x : wolf1.eat(foodGroup1)` makes absolutely no sense, besides providing the wrong input types, your treating `eat` as if it returns an `array` of `Food` which it certainly does not. On top of the technical issues I have no clue what in the world your trying to do.

Here's how to do what you asked for:

```
    public void eat(Food x, int b)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < b; i++
        {
            System.out.println("Wolf has eaten " + x + " " + i + " times.");   
        }
    }
```

If you need to save a list of all the foods consumed you can just add `foodGroup.Add(x);` in the loop.

Comment: Apparently `System.out.println("Wolf has eaten " + x " " + i + " times.");` has ')' expected, ';' expected and is not a statement but I can't see anything wrong with the line myself?

Comment: Forgot a `+` I think, try this instead: `System.out.println("Wolf has eaten " + x + " " + i + " times.");`